# Winter's Curse vs Duel vs Berserker's Call

Tags: dota

Which of those get higher priority and do not work with each other?

> Winter Wyvern strikes the battlefield with a maddening chill, cursing
>   a targeted enemy unit and freezing it in place. All of the target's
>   nearby allied units will go into an uncontrollable frenzy, attacking
>   the frozen ally for a short duration.

vs

> Calls the targeted enemy for a duel. Both you and the enemy will be
>   forced to attack each other and will both be unable to use items or
>   abilities. The victor gains permanent bonus damage.

vs

> Mogul Kahn focuses all of his enemies' hatred on him, causing them to
>   attack him at all costs.

Comment: Was vmy answer helpful or did you find something else ? if so could you share it please, im interested in those kind of mechanic :D

Comment: i will test it today. did not have the time yet. if i can confirm it (since i still find it strange) i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Berserker's called, a Dueling unit will attack alternatively Axe and his Duel opponent, canceling animation everytime due to the very low attack interval Berserker's call and Duel force.

In a similiar fashion, the hero under Wyvern's Winter's Curse will attack alternatively both the frozen ally and his Duel opponent, canceling his attack everytime. If you add berserker's call on top of that, it can either :

- Destroys the matrix
- Divide by 0
- Give a seizure to your hero

This alternative fashion come from the way the buffs work. While under one of those buff (Ill take Berserker's call  for example) the buffed Hero trigger and attack versus axe every 0.25 sec. However the attack action itself can be overwritten by a triggered attack toward another target forced by one of the other buff. Thus your hero will alternatively change target. Depending on when the buff are applied  (e.g. if the frequency of attack for either of those 3 buff is synched with another) the interaction between those spells become very weird.

If your hero has a really low attack rate (such as Alchemist with +Attack Speed items), you can attack fast enough to perform an hit on both target alternatively.

Comment: i forgot about berserkers call, so i edited my question. i never knew that spells would overwrite each other in alternating fashion.

Comment: @Wandang actually the spell dont "overwrite" each other, they just trigger an action at a certain frequency and those actions overwrite each other.

Comment: just like naga sirens ultimate does (every 0.5 seconds refreshes debuff)

Comment: If this is true, it's an insane combo to both Beserker's Call and Duel a unit: he will initiate an attack on Axe (potentially proccing Spin) but not actually deal any damage.

Comment: @Decency Actually, the triggered attack under the Duel buff triggers at a way faster rate than under Berserker's call.So depending on the poistion of Axe, a Dueling unit might not even have the time to change its facing angle thus never initiating an attack on Axe. However if the position of Axe is good enough, you can indeed proc helix;

Comment: @Deceny The attack trigger rate for Duel is 0.05 sec